# How to use a ref type prop with meterial-ui components like Popover? Trying to understand how to use 'action'= updatePosition() prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Problem: I'm trying to use the Popover component from @material-ui/core library and to use one of the props to resize my popover component manually. [Link to docs](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/#component-name)

Issue: The description of the 'action' prop says 'A ref for imperative actions. It currently only supports updatePosition() action'. Which I found a bit confusing.

I tried going through the original PR but not much help. Also in the popover demo, couldn't find it hence posting here.

Can you show me a simple class-based component code showing how to use 'imperative' ref props?

Really sorry if this is a PBKAC issue, in my defence I'm 1 month into React and found this confusing so other people might too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much documentation around this because it is not something you would typically need, since generally you should not be updating things in an imperative manner with React.

With this approach you pass a ref in to the `action` prop, and then Material-UI takes care of assigning an object (containing an `updatePosition` function) to the ref (to its `current` property). [Here is the place in the Popover code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.0/packages/material-ui/src/Popover/Popover.js#L353) where this occurs. It is done via [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle).

In the example below, there are two buttons within the Popover. One button moves the "Open Popover" button by adding a class to it imperatively. This is not the way I would typically add a class. Typically I would do it declaratively via a change of state such as shown here: https://codesandbox.io/s/demonstrate-popover-declarative-update-difl4, but using this declarative approach makes it unnecessary to use `updatePosition` (which is why it isn't generally needed). So I am only updating the button position imperatively to allow demonstrating `updatePosition`.

The second button in the Popover, calls `actionRef.current.updatePosition()` to tell the Popover to update its position based on the current position of its anchor element. `actionRef.current` points at the [object passed to useImperativeHandle](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.0/packages/material-ui/src/Popover/Popover.js#L356) by Material-UI.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  typography: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  alternateButtonPosition: {
    position: "relative",
    left: 100
  }
}));

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const actionRef = React.useRef();
  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-describedby={id}
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        action={actionRef}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <Typography className={classes.typography}>
          The content of the Popover.
          <br />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              if (
                anchorEl.className.indexOf(classes.alternateButtonPosition) >= 0
              ) {
                anchorEl.className = anchorEl.className.replace(
                  classes.alternateButtonPosition,
                  ""
                );
              } else {
                anchorEl.className += " " + classes.alternateButtonPosition;
              }
            }}
          >
            Move anchor element
          </Button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => actionRef.current.updatePosition()}
          >
            Update Popover Position
          </Button>
        </Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Demonstrate Popover updatePosition action]

And since you specifically asked for a class-based component example, here is the same example converted to a class:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const styles = theme => ({
  typography: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  alternateButtonPosition: {
    position: "relative",
    left: 100
  }
});

class SimplePopover extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { anchorEl: null };
    this.actionRef = React.createRef();
  }
  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };
  render() {
    const open = Boolean(this.state.anchorEl);
    const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;
    const anchorEl = this.state.anchorEl;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          aria-describedby={id}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          Open Popover
        </Button>
        <Popover
          id={id}
          action={this.actionRef}
          open={open}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: "bottom",
            horizontal: "left"
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "left"
          }}
        >
          <Typography className={this.props.classes.typography}>
            The content of the Popover.
            <br />
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => {
                if (
                  anchorEl.className.indexOf(
                    this.props.classes.alternateButtonPosition
                  ) >= 0
                ) {
                  anchorEl.className = anchorEl.className.replace(
                    this.props.classes.alternateButtonPosition,
                    ""
                  );
                } else {
                  anchorEl.className +=
                    " " + this.props.classes.alternateButtonPosition;
                }
              }}
            >
              Move anchor element
            </Button>
            <br />
            <br />
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => this.actionRef.current.updatePosition()}
            >
              Update Popover Position
            </Button>
          </Typography>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimplePopover);
```

[image: Edit Demonstrate Popover updatePosition action]